# Is there any disadvantages of using Redux Toolkit in react & react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When i started learning Redux Toolkit, it was very easy to implement than Redux, But i am just a beginner in react and react native. So should i learn Redux or Redux Toolkit? is there any downside of using Redux Toolkit in the future?

Comment: This is a question of opinion.  I suggest you learn both and make a decision on your own.

Comment: it saves your time, reduces boiler plate code, still you must know basic redux concepts

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro there is an official recommendation to this and even the "any disadvantages" part can be answered based on facts, so I'd guess it's valid to ask the question as there exists "an answer" to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Redux before, there are no disadvantages of using Redux Toolkit.

Since RTK is "just Redux", you can at any point where you need to do something unconventional still just use plain Redux as you were before side by side with RTK - and in all other cases gain the benefits from RTK.

Generally:

##### Redux Toolkit is the officially recommended approach to write *any* Redux code.

And that is the case since 2019.

This is stated in many places, but I'm just going to link the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic) here as reference.

Comment: Is there a way to use rtk in [stack overflow snippet](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde)? You need to add trk as a cdn hosted js file but I am unable to find one.

Comment: @HMR if you use the [UMD build](https://unpkg.com/browse/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.6.2/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js) you should be able to access `window.RTK`, but I have no idea how stack overflow snippets really work